# How to calculate relative percent difference from samples with the same ID dynamically in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to calculate relative percent difference, RPD = |a-b|/((a+b)/2), by isolating rows with the same sample ID. Here is an example dataframe:

```
IDs <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
values <- c(1.2, 1.36, 2.87, 3, 2.54, 2.33)

df <- tibble(IDs, values)
```

The problem I am running into is that I am trying to do this in a shiny app, so the sample ID's and the number of RPD calculations I am doing each time can vary (ie. `IDs <- c("D", "D", "E", "E")` or an equivalent example). I was trying to find a way to use `group_by`, but I am not sure how to extract the individual values from the "group" made by from grouping by Samlpe ID. Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function `mutate` from package `dplyr` is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(IDs) %>%
  mutate(DIF = (max(values)-min(values))/mean(values))
```

I would also recommend to check if you really have only 2 entries in your data with the same ID, in order to avoid incorrect results:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(IDs) %>%
  mutate(DIF = ifelse(length(IDs)==2, (max(values)-min(values))/mean(values), NA))
```